# When are endorsement rewards from the last block in a cycle unfrozen?

Tags: baking, rewards, endorsement

I've been using TZStats' API and noticed that endorsements done in the last block of a cycle don't count in the endorsement rewards for that cycle.

That does seem to make sense, seeing the endorsement rewards don't show up in the blockchain until the succeeding block. For example, if an endorser has endorsed last block 233472 in cycle 56, the endorsement rewards are registered in block 233473.

I would thus assume that the endorsement reward from block 233472 would not be released from frozen balance in cycle 62 like the rest of the rewards for cycle 56, but in cycle 63.

Are all of these assumptions correct?